# How to compute lower edge of a credible interval for a beta distribution in python?

Tags: python, beta-distribution, scipy

Suppose I flip a coin 584,369 times and observe 5,257 heads and 579,112 tails. I wish to know the lower edge of the 90% credible interval for the probability that the next flip will come up heads.

I believe:

- I could use a [beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with alpha=5257 and beta=579112.
- I want the value of the [cumulative distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) at 0.05.
- I could calculate that in Python with SciPy using the betainc and beta [special functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html).

I installed SciPy, and wrote:

```
from scipy.special import betainc, beta

numer = betainc(5257, 579112, 0.05)
denom = beta(5257, 579112)

print numer
print denom
print numer / denom
```

I get

```
1.0
0.0
./foo.py:6: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  print numer / denom
inf
```

That is not what I want.  I believe [this web page calculator](http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573227) says I want 0.008793824176376785502, which is plausible (close to 5257/(5257+579112)=0.00899602819451).

So: are my beliefs correct?  How do I calculate this lower edge in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Friend of mine answered this: I want the inverse cumulative distribution, i.e. the place on the X axis where the cumulative distribution is at 0.05.

In SciPy, the easiest thing is [btdtri](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.btdtri.html#scipy.special.btdtri).

```
print btdtri(5257, 579112, 0.05)
```

gives

```
0.0087938241764
```